# How can I print a the outcome value of this script live to a property?

Tags: python, game-engine

So I made this script:

```
import bge
from bge import logic

scene = logic.getCurrentScene()

cube = logic.getCurrentController().owner
speed = cube.getLinearVelocity()

cube['Velocity']=speed`
```

as you can see, speed is the holder for the outcome of the script. I tried to print it to a property called Velocity the way someone told me but it doesn't work. Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: there's a ` behind speed. If it's meant like that then that's the mistake. If not you might want to post the console output if there's any error. To do so you have go to 'window' and then 'toggle system console'

Comment: No, I accidently placed it there, it isn't in the script in blender.

Answer (score 1):

## Semantic

### Precision

This is a problem of not being precise enough.

#### Request

> I tried to print it to a property called Velocity the way someone told me but it doesn't work

Your code does not "print" anything. I guess you meant "copy", "assign" or "fill". Printing usually involves a call to "print".

#### Code

The code itself is correct. It places a value into the property. You can verify that be adding

```
print("Velocity:", cube["Velocity"])
```

The issue is that you call a velocity "speed". While Python will not care, you as a reader instantly get an incorrect though of what it is.

- **Speed** is a scalar (a number) like 2 km/h.
- **Velocity** is a direction and a size = a vector for example: (1.0, 0, 0) = along one unit along the X-axis.

Luckily the property name brings the reader's mind back to where it should be.

So lets use the other term to make it more clear:

```
import bge
from bge import logic

scene = logic.getCurrentScene()

cube = logic.getCurrentController().owner
velocity = cube.getLinearVelocity()

cube['Velocity'] = velocity
```

There is not functional change, but the semantic is more precise.

#### "but it doesn't work"!

Unfortunately you did not tell what "doesn't work". As said, assigning the velocity to the property does work (the print statement shows that).

I assume you wanted to use Game/Show Debug Properties to let the BGE print the property value to the screen.

This will indeed not work.

The BGE debug output only supports properties created via GUI. The Debug Renderer expects the format you entered at the GUI. This means when "Velocity" is a float, the value should be float too.

Linear Velocity is a vector (see above). A vector value can't be converted to a float and not shown in the debug output.

[Edit:]

You can use a string property and fill in a string representation:

```
cube['VelocityText'] = str(velocity)
```

[/Edit]

## The question

is ... do you want the velocity or the speed?